# Unable to locate package neofetch on apt install neofetch

Tags: installation, apt, packages, locate

I'm trying to install neofetch on a Linux server running Debian 8, I'm already on root, I type `apt install neofetch` but it returns `E: Unable to locate package neofetch`. I tried `apt-get install neofetch` as well and got the same result.
Can anyone help me identify why can't I install neofetch?

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630442) helped me. But in my case, I had to uncomment some lines in `Parrot 5.x Repositories` part.
`deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ lts main contrib non-free` 
`deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ lts-security main contrib non-free`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).